# tsconfig paths with jest.config

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths

I would like to use the paths functionality of the tsconfig. But when using it with `jest` I am getting problems. This is the guide I followed to implement this: https://medium.com/@fmoessle/typescript-paths-with-ts-node-ts-node-dev-and-jest-671deacf6428

My `tsconfig.json` is

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6",
      "es2017",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths" : {
      "@testUtils": ["./entities/tests/utils", "./testUtils"],
      "@testUtils/*": ["./entities/tests/utils/*", "./testUtils/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": [
      "./src/custom_typings",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

My `jest.config.ts` is

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
import { JestConfigWithTsJest, pathsToModuleNameMapper } from "ts-jest";
import { compilerOptions } from "./tsconfig.json";

const jestConfig: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["dist/", "node_modules/"],

  // this enables us to use tsconfig-paths with jest
  modulePaths: [compilerOptions.baseUrl],
  moduleNameMapper: pathsToModuleNameMapper(compilerOptions.paths),
};

export default jestConfig
```

When I run the tests, it fails with:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Configuration error:
    
    Could not locate module @testUtils mapped as:
    [
      "./entities/tests/utils",
      "./testUtils"
    ].
    
    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/^@testUtils$/": "[
          "./entities/tests/utils",
          "./testUtils"
        ]"
      },
      "resolver": undefined
    }
```

The folder structure is:

```
src/
├─ entities/tests/utils/
├─ testUtils/
tsconfig.json
jest.config.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

It works after removing the `./` in front of the paths in `tsconfig` so:

Instead of this:

```
    "paths" : {
      "@testUtils": ["./entities/tests/utils", "./testUtils"],
      "@testUtils/*": ["./entities/tests/utils/*", "./testUtils/*"]
    },
```

This

```
    "paths" : {
      "@testUtils": ["entities/tests/utils", "testUtils"],
      "@testUtils/*": ["entities/tests/utils/*", "testUtils/*"]
    },
```